# notepad++ - Applying CSS styles for SCSS files?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, web-development

In Notepad++, I have some SCSS files for which I would like the syntax to be highlighted like CSS files are. How do I do this in Notepad++?

In other words, I would like to apply the same styles to SCSS files as I do CSS files.

Comment: This is a good idea, but won't give you a perfect solution.
The problem is that Notepad++ won't understand Sassy comments (`//`).
An alternative solution *might* be found at
https://github.com/marvinlabs/notepad-plus-plus-scss-syntax-highlighting
- *or* - at
https://github.com/robertochiaveri/notepadppSASSsyntax.
(I don't have the time to write a proper answer right now.)

Answer (score 14):

#### I would like to apply the same styles to SCSS files as I do CSS files.

This is done using the **Style Configurator**:

- Menu > Settings > Style Configurator
- Select "CSS" in the "Language" box
- Add "scss" to the "User ext" field (you can add multiple extension separated by space)
- Click "Save & Close"
- Reopen your ".scss" file to see the highlighting.

  [image]